# how to add value into List<Map<String, Object>>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add a value to an `ArrayList`.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.put(1,"foo", (Object)"bar");
```

But, this does not work. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: This won't compile. Please give us the real code.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? Does nothing appear to happen and the list is unchanged?

Comment: Also, you need to provide a Map<String, Object> to add to the list. Wrap your data values in one.

Comment: @ifly6 well, something that does not even compile can not work, so OP is right on that one...

Comment: I'm just writing and not compiled yet because eclipse says there's an error.

Comment: It probably says something more specific than "there's an error".

Comment: The element that you add to your `list` **must be** a `Map`.

Comment: An interesting way to solve it would be to create a method that returns `Map`, i.e. initialises them based off some provided values and returns the Map. Then, you can call that method whenever required.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
list.add(map);
```

Comment: so i have to create Map first, and put it into Arraylist?

Comment: @kishiberohan for sure, cause you have a list of Maps. You can put into list only objects of type (or which extends/implements class/interface) that you defined in first row

Comment: Will that not create any memory leak as you are adding map to list. you will be required to clear it explicitly,

Answer (score 0):

**private List<Map<String, Object>> map_formula;**

To save to database pass this JSON:-

```
{
"map_formula" : [ 
        {
            "A+" : "if(price<400),\"40000\",0",
            "B" : "",
            "c" : "",
            "d" : "",
            "e" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "poor" : "value for poor",
            "good" : "300",
            "average" : "300",
            "excellent" : "300"
        }
    ]
}
```

To extract from the database:-

```
 for (Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap : obj.getMap_formula()) {

                        if (stringObjectMap.containsKey("key_name"){
                            System.err.println("calculation started");
                        }
                    }
```